# How do i go about achieving this content box using CSS3 while maintaining maximum compatibility

Tags: html, css

advise me how I would go about achieving this layout.

I really don't have much code to input, this screenshot is taken from a table designed website, using images for all borders, is their an alternative using CSS3? A hint-start would be appreciated.

Here's what I tried so far:

```css
#content {
  background-color: #141414;
  margin: 24px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 20px;
  border-top: 2px #ff0000 solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section id="content">
  <article>
    <hgroup>
      <h1>lorem </h1>
      <br />
    </hgroup>
    lorem ipsum
  </article>
</section>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes is there an alternative ... but in order to fit the rules of SO you need to include what have you tried, not just "code me this".

Comment: If you are talking about positioning, you might have a look at `position: absolute`, `top`, and maybe `left`, as well as margins. However, if you are more interested in the look and feel, `border-radius`, gradient backgrounds, even `box-shadow` come into play.

Comment: I see you added code. Good. Actually you're looking good so far, with the colored background, the color and the rounded corners? Where are you stuck, or do you just not feel like writing the rest of the code?

Comment: @GolezTrol That's what I've got as far http://i.imgur.com/REwsSLo.png, My aim is coding the borders and the gradient without using images, is that possible? and I'm still with the outer box content, don't know how I'd go about the inner box. I looked up examples on the web and I saw someone using border-image: linear-gradient but that didn't work well for me, a brief start would help a lot.

Comment: @János Weisz Thanks for your input, I'm more interested in the feel of it as doing the shiny silver borders with CSS3, And here's a quick question, How do i add a border on top of the border-top? as it's shown in the first image. Thanks!

Comment: For the gradients, you can use a [gradient generator](http://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator) which saves you a lot of trouble. The inner border seems to be ridged: http://jsfiddle.net/yo2L5ppn/

Comment: @GolezTrol Haha dude, You're a f$#king legend. thanks a bunch for the jsfiddle code. Post your comment as answer, One question left how do i play with the ridged border brightness, on the original screenshot the border images shine and have a shadow if you noticed with a separate background from the outer dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can make out in your image, this should be pretty close. But since I don't know what you intend to use it for it may be way off the mark.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bpb4j2f4/2/)

```css
body {
    background: #000;
}

.box {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 50px auto;
    background: #222;
    border: 1px solid #444444;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #141414;
}

.header {
    height: 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444444;
    
    background: rgb(68,68,68);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(68,68,68,1) 0%, rgba(47,47,47,1) 49%, rgba(19,19,19,1) 50%, rgba(1,1,1,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(68,68,68,1)), color-stop(49%,rgba(47,47,47,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(19,19,19,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(1,1,1,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(68,68,68,1) 0%,rgba(47,47,47,1) 49%,rgba(19,19,19,1) 50%,rgba(1,1,1,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(68,68,68,1) 0%,rgba(47,47,47,1) 49%,rgba(19,19,19,1) 50%,rgba(1,1,1,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(68,68,68,1) 0%,rgba(47,47,47,1) 49%,rgba(19,19,19,1) 50%,rgba(1,1,1,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(68,68,68,1) 0%,rgba(47,47,47,1) 49%,rgba(19,19,19,1) 50%,rgba(1,1,1,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#444444', endColorstr='#010101',GradientType=0 );
}

.content {
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
}

.inner_box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    bottom: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    right: 25%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #969696;
    box-shadow:  inset 0 0 8px rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #0f0f0f;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="inner_box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Just a question, I've already used ::before, is it more compatible to use your a div and a class instead?

Comment: You've used :before for what?

Comment: If you mean browser compatibility you need to use :before not ::before. The two : isn't understood by older browsers. They all understand single : As for wether a pseudo element is right in this case; that's up to you

Comment: When I say "they all understand single : " I mean IE8 and above.